# c# ASP.NET newb redirect question

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey I'm trying to get this working but I am not a c# programmer. i got this code to display you what i would like to do. but of cause its not working. Error: CS1519: Invalid Token...

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    if(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] === "this-domain.com"){
        Response.Redirect("http://other-domain.com", true);
    }
</script>
```

Microsoft .NET Framework-Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET-Version:2.0.50727.3601

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] === "this-domain.com"
```

Should be

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] == "this-domain.com"
```

And you need to enclose the whole statement in bee stings `<% %>`

Comment: Editted spotted something else missing

Answer (score 3):

Try changing === to ==

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `===` to `==`.

Answer (score 1):

=== is not needed,== is enough.

and remove
 script tag.
 and use Scriptlets ie <% %>

```
<%

  if(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] == "this-domain.com"){
        Response.Redirect("http://other-domain.com", true);
    }
 %>
```